# Radius of convergence of a series with coefficients satisfying $n a _ { n } < b _ { n } <n^2a _ { n } $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\left\{ a _ { n } \right\} _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty }$ and $\left\{ b _ { n } \right\} _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty }$ be sequences of pesitive
real numbers such that $n a _ { n } < b _ { n } <n^2a _ { n } ,$ for all
$n \geq 2 .$ If the radius of convergence ofthe power series $\sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty } a _ { n } x ^ { n }$ is $4 ,$ then the power series $\sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty } b_ { n } x ^ { n }$

(1) Converges for all $x$ with $| x | < 2$

(2) Converges for all $x$ with $| x | > 2$

(3) Does not converge for any $x$ with $| x | > 2$

(4) Does not converge for any $x$ with $| x | < 2$

Can we say that the series with coefficients $na_n$ and $n^2a_n$ has radius of convergence 4, then the series with coefficients $b_n$ has the same?

Comment: Going from $a_n$ to $na_n$ and $n^2a_n$ having the same radius of convergence seems like a bit of a leap. Do you have anything to back that up? Going from $na_n$ and $n^2a_n$ implying $b_n$ has the same radius as the first two seems quite reasonable but also needs an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive $x$ we have $\sum na_nx^{n} \leq \sum b_nx^{n} \leq \sum n^{2}a_nx^{n}$. But $\sum na_nx^{n}$ and $\sum n^{2}a_nx^{n}$ have radius of convergence $4$ (by the formula for radius of convergence, or by comparison test). Hence $\sum b_nx^{n} $ converges iff $\sum a_nx^{n}$ does, whenever $x \geq 0, x \neq \pm 4$. This is enough to conclude that the  second power series has radius of convergence $4$.